# RadToolTip: how to get it to show on mouse over event triggered on a label control

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, telerik

I'm trying to get my tool tip to show when a `OnMouseOver` event is triggered on a label control. I get a javascript exception "Object expected" on `OnMouseOver="ShowToolTip()`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowTooltip() {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            var tooltip = $find("<%# rttStatus.ClientID %>");
            //API: show the tooltip
            tooltip.show();
        }, 10);
    }
</script>

<telerik:RadTreeList>
    <Columns>
        <telerik:TreeListTemplateColumn HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" UniqueName="Status">
            <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblStatus" Text='<%# GetStatus(Eval("Status")) %>' 
               OnMouseOver='ShowToolTip()' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle VerticalAlign="Middle" HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="80px" />
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="80px" />
        </telerik:TreeListTemplateColumn>
    </Columns>            
</telerik:RadTreeList>

<telerik:RadToolTip runat="server" ID="rttStatus" HideEvent="FromCode" Position="MiddleRight" Title="Raison"
                    Width="150px" Height="70px" Animation="Fade" ShowEvent="OnClick" ShowDelay="0" ManualClose="false"
                    RelativeTo="Element" TargetControlID="lblStatus" IsClientID="true" Text="this is a test" Skin="Telerik" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@David, I found a better solution without any javascript involved, this time using the `RadToolTipManager`:

```
<telerik:RadTreeList>
    <Columns>
        <telerik:TreeListTemplateColumn HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" UniqueName="Status">
            <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblStatus" Text='<%# GetStatus(Eval("Status")) %>' ToolTip='<%# Eval("Reason") %>'/>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle VerticalAlign="Middle" HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="80px" />
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="80px" />
        </telerik:TreeListTemplateColumn>
    </Columns>            
</telerik:RadTreeList>

<telerik:RadToolTipManager ID="RadToolTipManager1" runat="server" RelativeTo="Element"
    Position="MiddleRight" AutoTooltipify="true" ContentScrolling="Default" Width="150"
    Height="10" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but the original issue is that your function is named *ShowTooltip*, but in your `OnMouseOver` you have *ShowTool**T**ip*

Answer (score 0):

You could try removing the `OnMouseOver='ShowToolTip()'` from lblStatus and change `ShowEvent="OnClick"` to `ShowEvent="OnMouseOver"` on rttStatus. [Source](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/tooltip-controlling-show.html)

You'll also have to place the `telerik:RadToolTip` inside the `ItemTemplate` of the `telerik:TreeListTemplateColumn`.

```
<telerik:RadTreeList>
    <Columns>
        <telerik:TreeListTemplateColumn HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" UniqueName="Status">
            <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblStatus" Text='<%# GetStatus(Eval("Status")) %>' 
                          OnMouseOver='ShowToolTip()' />

    <telerik:RadToolTip runat="server" ID="rttStatus" HideEvent="FromCode" Position="MiddleRight" Title="Raison"
                        Width="150px" Height="70px" Animation="Fade" ShowEvent="OnClick" ShowDelay="0" ManualClose="false"
                        RelativeTo="Element" TargetControlID="lblStatus" IsClientID="true" Text="this is a test" Skin="Telerik" />

            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle VerticalAlign="Middle" HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="80px" />
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="80px" />
        </telerik:TreeListTemplateColumn>
    </Columns>            
</telerik:RadTreeList>
```

You could also try with the 1 `telerik:RadToolTip` below, but change the javascript:

```
from: var tooltip = $find("<%# rttStatus.ClientID %>");
to:   var tooltip = $find("<%= rttStatus.ClientID %>");  //Since  we're not in a data-binding syntax the '#' should be replaces with '='
or:   var tooltip = $find("rttStatus"); // The telerik example shows using the literal ID of the control instead of the ClientID.
```

[source](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/tooltip/examples/clientsideapi/defaultcs.aspx)

Comment: If this works then that would mean that the javascript block is not needed

Comment: Sorry I didn't spot this earlier.  You'll need to put the telerik:RadToolTip inside the telerik:RadTreeList ItemTemplate

Comment: Hmm... the last thing I can think of is to go back to using the js block, but have var tooltip = $find("<%= rttStatus.ClientID %>");